# Identify the cover model from an issue of Life Magazine

Tags: identification, fashion, photography

Could someone identify the cover model for the Life Magazine issue dated August 22, 1969: 
[image]
https://twitter.com/historylvrsclub/status/1050574006632570880/photo/1

The issue itself is silent on this fact. The article referred to is titled: ["That young New York look".](https://www.oldlifemagazines.com/august-22-1969-life-magazine.html)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the photographer [Vernon Merritt III](http://theharlow.net/vernon-merritt-iii-summer-of-69/) didn't document the name:

> [image]
> Woman Possibly Model, W. Long Hair wearing short skirt, lace top & sandals, walking up street, re story on New York look in fashion. (Photo by Vernon Merritt III/The LIFE Picture Collection/Getty Images)
>
> [Image provided by Getty Images.](https://www.gettyimages.de/detail/nachrichtenfoto/woman-with-long-hair-wearing-short-skirt-lace-top-nachrichtenfoto/53368333)
> by Vernon Merritt III
> (— This picture taken from [Fine Art America](https://fineartamerica.com/featured/woman-possibly-model-w-long-hair-wea-vernon-merritt-iii.html))

Notice that this version above as it appears on Fine Art America is mirrored. The more often found version is in the same direction as the version on the magazine cover:

[image]

And clicking on this one reveals a part of the print on the newspaper

[image]

---

The photographer [really liked this setup:](https://pleasurephoto.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/woman-possibly-model-w-long-hair-wearing-short-skirt-lace-top-sandals-walking-up-street-re-story-on-new-york-look-in-fashion-1969-photo-vernon-merritt-iii/%22new-york-look%22-in-fashion-1969-vernon-merritt-iii-1969-new-york-ny-us/)

[image]

Comment: It seems your photo is reversed (look at the cars).

Comment: @Spencer Yeah, *one* of those two is.  But I fail to ascertain which is which. I just thought that for a magazine cover such a 'switch' would be fairly common compared to photo archives?

Comment: Headlights are facing toward the camera -- this is New York, so in your picture, they're facing the wrong way for that side of the street.

Comment: Plus, the newspaper. At the bottom left of the cover photo you've got three boldface lines with a light-grey "BLUES" behind them. On the picture in this answer it is pretty clear it has been mirrored (the "S" is easiest to recognize, it's the wrong way around).

Comment: That second picture is a nice find. I don't think it's a recreated setup though, just another shot of the same model.